# Is it possible to use different L1 / L2 regularization parameters for different sets of weights in chainer or pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

(As an example) When implementing a simple linear model for `noutput` target values as a neural network in pytorch:

```
l1=L.Linear(ninput, noutput)
```

(call)

```
y = self.l1(x)
return y
```

Adding this hook will do L2 regularization on all weights, imposing the same *alpha*=0.01 everywhere:

```
optimizer.add_hook(optimizer.WeightDecay(rate=0.01))
```

Is it possible to use a different *alpha* for each set of weights leading from all `ninput` input units to one of the `noutput` output units?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we are working in pytorch it is possible to add other **scalars** to loss function yourself. So assume loss from you classfier is L ( assume it is a cross entropy loss ) and you have a linear layer defined as:

```
l1 = nn.Linear(in,out)
```

Now if you want to have different regularization on each set of weights then all you have to do is gather weights using ( i.e select using index) and add to the final loss:

```
loss = L (crossentropy loss) + sum ( alpha * norm(l1.weight[k]))
```

alpha the hyper-parameters and norm is mostly L2 norm,in pytorch it is just `torch.norm(l1.weight)` where index k is a tensor of indices of weights you want to select. Finally, you don't need to do the global regularization as you have done in the code.

Comment: The OP did not ask for different regularizations in different layers. The question asks for different regularizer for each output weights in a single layer.

Comment: Oh ok.. I think i read the question wrong. I edited my answer. Thanks for pointing that out @layog

Comment: Thanks! Indeed one can just implement the weight regularization oneself and make it a component of the loss function. Nice and clean solution.